# C# class multiple data in/out; read all previous answers

Tags: c#, class, tuples

I created a join & renewal forms for horse club. Mem cost depends on type mem, method pmt, & if hard-copy newsletter.  Mem can self-join, self-renew or officer can do it. So have several aspx programs do almost identical thing. Not an expert so did all calcs in code-behind. Now have bright idea to create a class. Read everything here on returning multiple values. Thought tuples would work because incoming data consists of string, double and bool so wrote this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class JoinRenew
{
public JoinRenew()
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}


public Tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double> 
    CalcMemCost(string PayMethod, double MemCostOrig, double InsCostOrig, double NLfeeOrig, bool bNewsltrEmail)
{
    double MemCost = 0;
    double MemPPR = 0;
    double InsCost = 0;
    double InsPPR = 0;
    double NLfee = 0;
    double NLPPR = 0;

    if (PayMethod == "Check")
    {
        MemCost = MemCostOrig;
        MemPPR = 0;
        InsCost = InsCostOrig;
        InsPPR = 0;
        if (bNewsltrEmail)
        {
            NLfee = 0;
            NLPPR = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            NLfee = NLfeeOrig;
            NLPPR = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (PayMethod == "PayPal")
    {
        MemCost = MemCostOrig;
        MemPPR = (MemCost * .029) + .30;
        InsCost = InsCostOrig;
        InsPPR = (InsCost * .029) + .30;
        if (bNewsltrEmail)
        {
            NLfee = 0;
            NLPPR = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            NLfee = NLfeeOrig;
            NLPPR = (NLfee * .029) + .30;
        }
    }
    return new Tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double>(MemCost, MemPPR, InsCost, InsPPR, NLfee, NLPPR);
}
```

}

No laughing. This is exactly what I want it to do. But I can't figure out how to call it/use it in the code-behind.  All previous answers assume frame of reference & knowledge I don't have. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple class of your tupel. Like:

```
class Data
{
    public double field1 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and give it as reference parameter to your method:

```
public void Method(ref Data myData)
```

{
        ...
    }

Hope that helps...